# PHP SQL in 1 query

Tags: php, mysql

Excuse me, for simple guestion. I am new in Sql. So, I have a coouple of sql query, I would like to write this sql in 1 Query!

```
$sql1=select 'max(id) as max1 FROM table where status_id=1 LIMIT 1';
$sql2=select 'max(id) as max2 FROM table where status_id=2 LIMIT 1';
$sql3=select 'max(id) as max3 FROM table where status_id=3 LIMIT 1';
$sql4=select 'max(id) as max4 FROM table where status_id=4 LIMIT 1';

$query1=mysql_query($sql1);
$fetch1=mysql_fetch_array($query1);
$query2=mysql_query($sql2);
$fetch2=mysql_fetch_array($query2);
$query3=mysql_query($sql3);
$fetch3=mysql_fetch_array($query3);
$query4=mysql_query($sql4);
$fetch4=mysql_fetch_array($query4);

echo 'Max ID numbers are:'.$fetch1['max1'].'; '.$fetch2['max2'].'; '.$fetch3['max3'].'; '.$fetch4['max4'].'';
```

How can I use write these 4 sql in one query and fetch suitable ID? I tried MYSQL UNION, was'nt any result.

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `group by`:

```
select status_id, max(id) as maxValue FROM `table` 
where status_id in (1,2,3,4) group by status_id
```

Comment: This should be the answer. I wonder where the upvotes from the other came from.

Answer (score 5):

Use this query

```
SELECT `status_id`, 
       max(`id`) as `max` 
FROM table 
GROUP BY `status_id`
```

This will give you all pairs of `status_id` and the respective `max(id)` per `status_id`. You can fetch the result then in a usual (`while`) loop.

<sup>Standard disclaimer: [`mysql_`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) functions are deprecated. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.</sup>